# How to host a privately shared website on Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

I've created this html+javascript based website via [jalbum](http://jalbum.net/en/). And I'm currently uploading it to Google Drive.

Before Google Drive, I was uploading it to Dropbox, but stopped that upload, believing that Google Drive has access control over who can view a folder's contents, and I had previously hosted a website before on Google Drive, which could be viewed flawlessly.

But while the upload is almost complete, I was searching again on how to upload a website to the drive, and couldn't find any solution to share it privately. All articles were detailing on how to make the folder as *public* while I actually need it to be *private*.

So I'm posting this question here, to ask how to host a website on Google Drive with password protected, or email authorized access to the contents of the website?

Is there any way Drive could be used to host the website? Because my upload of about 1.4gb is almost complete, and I also like the email collaboration of a folder's contents on Drive.

I don't want to do it via FTP hosting websites, because that would take a long time, and cannot be updated easily enough.

Comment: Well, I know about that option, but it still needs to be shared public.. `Create a new folder in Drive and share it as "Public on the web."` ... How can I add another access level? You mean a level up? Or a sub-level for the website folder?

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive had a built-in feature to host web files it was available since 2016. Ref. [Deprecating web hosting support in Google Drive](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html).

Depending on your website structure one option to use Google Drive as the file repository and control access management system is to use the Drive Service and Html Service of Google Apps Script to create a web application. Start by learning about creating web apps using Google Apps Script by reading the official guide -> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web.