# Maintain URLs of Subfolders and Files on Google Drive for Image Hosting

Tags: google-drive, image-storage

Is it possible to maintain a file's original filename on Google Drive?

I'm trying to see if I can use Google Drive to host images for a website I'm building. Right now, the shareable-link generates a hash for each file. But I'll be hosting quite a lot of images and want at least the names of the sub-folders and files to be guessable.

How do I maintain the URL format as such:

```
<folderID>/sub_folder/filename.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time it's not possible to use Google Drive as file hosting that maintains a folder structure.

This was a supported feature but it was retired few years ago.

Related

- [How to host a privately shared website on Google Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/57405/88163)
- [How to host my existing website with Google Drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74548/88163)